# Double Integral Polar coordinates definition

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I want to write the following double integral in polar coordinates :
$$\int_{\sqrt{2}/2}^{\sqrt{2}} \int_{y}^{\sqrt{4-y^2}} e^{x^2+y^2} \, \mathrm d x \mathrm d y$$

The region is a circle centered at $(0,0)$ and with radius $2$, and y=x.
At his point I am stuck. Can you please explain how to find the polar equivalent of this integral? Thank you.

So it equals to the following integral in polar coordinates?
$$\int_{\sqrt{2}/2}^{\sqrt{2}} \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} e^{r^2}r \, \mathrm d r \mathrm d o$$

Comment: "The region is a circle centered at $(2,0)$ and with radius $1$" you might want to check that. Try plotting $y\le x\le\sqrt{4-y^2}$ to see.

Comment: edited @SimplyBeautifulArt , also try plotting sqrt(2)/2 <= x <= sqrt(2)?

Answer (score 1):

The condition $1/\sqrt 2\le y\le \surd 2$ chops a horizontal slice
off the circle of radius 2 and leaves a circular cap.
The intersections of $y=1/\surd 2$ with the circle
are at $(x,y)=(\pm \sqrt{7/2},\sqrt{1/2})$.
The condition $x\ge y$ means the region is also restricted to the first quadrant,
where the diagonal hits the circle at $(x,y)=(\surd 2,\surd 2)$,
and $x\le \sqrt{4-y^2}$ means $x^2+y^2\le 4$ means we stay inside the circle.
The diagonal hits the circle at a lower $x$-value, so the region is
restricted to the right of where the diagonal $x=y$ hits the horizontal $y=1/\surd 2$,
(which has has distance $r=1$ to the origin)
and to the left where the horizontal $y=1/\surd 2$ hits the circle.
In polar coordinates
$$
I=\int_{1/\surd 2}^{\surd 2} dy \int_y^{\sqrt{4-y^2}} dx e^{x^+y^2}
$$
$$
=\int_1^2 r dr e^{r^2}
\int_{\arcsin(1/r\surd 2)}^{\pi/4} d\phi
$$
$$
=\int_1^2 r dr e^{r^2}
[\pi/4-\arcsin\frac{1}{r\surd 2}]
$$
$$
=
\pi/4 \int_1^2 r dr e^{r^2}
-\int_1^2 r dr e^{r^2}
\arcsin\frac{1}{r\surd 2}
$$
$$
=
\pi/8 \int_1^4 du e^u
-\int_1^2 r dr e^{r^2}
\arcsin\frac{1}{r\surd 2}.
$$
$$
=
\frac{\pi}{8} e^3(e-1)
-\int_1^2 r dr e^{r^2}
\arcsin\frac{1}{r\surd 2}.
$$
By partial integration
$$
\int r dr e^{r^2} \arcsin\frac{1}{rc}
=
\frac12 e^{r^2}\arcsin\frac{1}{rc}
+\int \frac12 e^{r^2} \frac{1}{r\sqrt{r^2c^2-1}} dr
$$

With $r^2=u$
$$
\frac12 \int e^{r^2} \frac{1}{r\sqrt{r^2c^2-1}} dr
$$
$$
=\frac14 \int e^{u} \frac{1}{u\sqrt{uc^2-1}} du
$$
with $uc^2-1=v$, $dv=c^2du$
$$
=\frac14 \int e^{(v+1)/c^2} \frac{1}{(v+1)\sqrt{v}} dv
$$
$$
=\frac14 e^{1/c^2}\int e^{v/c^2} \frac{1}{(v+1)\sqrt{v}} dv
$$
which may not have a closed form but might be written as an infinite sum by the
Taylor expansion of $e^{v/c^2}$...

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ denote the positive quadrant of $x^2+y^2=2^2$. The line $y=x$, i.e. $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$, meets $A$'s arc at $(\sqrt{2},\,\sqrt{2})$. If you draw a diagram, you'll notice we're integrating over the points in $A$ below this line (and hence at lower $\theta$), but above $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, i.e. $\theta=\arcsin\frac{1}{r\sqrt{2}}$. Note the region of interest is therefore restricted to $r\ge\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. So our integral is$$\int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^2re^{r^2}dr\int_{\arcsin\frac{1}{r\sqrt{2}}}^{\pi/4}d\theta=\int_{1/\sqrt{2}}^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\arcsin\frac{1}{r\sqrt{2}}\right)re^{r^2}dr.$$